# Approximating an expression for $\rho$ tends to zero

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need to approximate the following expression within $-M\leq z \leq M$ for $\rho$ tends to zero,

$\frac{\sqrt{\rho^2+(z+M)^2}-(z+M)}{\sqrt{\rho^2+(z-M)^2}-(z-M)}$,
where $M$ is a constant and $z$ is a variable

My lecturer insists that a Taylor expansion about $\rho=0$ will produce the appropriate approximation, however, even with Mathematica, I was not able to get any sensible approximation.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Mathematica]

I suppose your lecturer was thinking of this?

Comment: Yup it is, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Denote $r= \frac{\rho^2}{(z\pm M)^2}$ and expand

$$\frac{\sqrt{\rho^2+(z+M)^2}-(z+M)}{\sqrt{\rho^2+(z-M)^2}-(z-M)}\\
 = \frac{z+M (1+ \frac{\rho^2}{2(z+M)^2}+O(r^2))-(z+M)}{ M -z +O(r)-(z-M)}\\
 = \frac{ \frac{\rho^2}{2(z+M)}}{ 2(M-z)}+O(r)^2\approx \frac{\rho^2}{4(M^2-z^2)}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help!